# How to enable the checkbox when the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a requirement where i have to email textbox followed by submit button.
Once the user enter the email id and clicked on submit there is checked box set to enable.
How to do this using js & jsp. as i am new to js & jsp.
Attached Mock design. 
[Sample Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Rkc.png)

```
    <div class = "owner-search">

<input type="text" id="emailText" value="ID: EMail..">

<button onclick="emailFunction()">Search</button>

<script>
function emailFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("emailText").value;
alert("X value...." + x);
document.getElementById("emailText").value = x;
var dummyData = "dummyData";
alert("Dummy_new_data......" + dummyData); 
//document.getElementById('emailText').value = x;
}
</script>
<%
String name=request.getParameter("dummyData");
if(name!=null){
out.println("emailText12sssssssss345" + name);
}
else{
out.println("ESLE ..... " + name);
}
%>
<% String st="<script> document.writeln(dummyData)</script>";
if(st!=null){
out.println("value=......."+st); 
} 
else{
out.println("value else=......."+st); 
}
%>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code. What are you stuck on? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.